# Strictly increasing difference between adjacent elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function expanding(l) that takes as input a list of integer l and returns True if the absolute difference between each adjacent pair of elements strictly increases.

I tried to execute this code but this isn't returning correct value for some lists.

```py
def expanding(l):
 for i in range(0,len(l)-3):
  if (abs(l[i+2]-l[i+1])>abs(l[i+1]-l[i])):
   Answer=True
  else:
   Answer=False
 return Answer
```

`expanding([1,3,7,2,-3])`  should be False but the output is `True`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def expanding(l):
 for i in range(0,len(l)-2):
  if (abs(l[i+2]-l[i+1])>abs(l[i+1]-l[i])):
   Answer=True
  else:
   Answer=False
   return Answer
 return Answer

expanding([1,3,7,2,-3])
```

As soon as you know that one item is out of order you should answer False for the whole list without waiting,so that other pairs not change the answer.

Also note the change from `range(0,len(l)-3)` to `range(0,len(l)-2)`. The original implementation was missing the last pair of list elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use a temporary variable to store the difference, and exit once you reach a non-increasing difference.

```py
def expanding(l):

    dif = abs(l[1] - l[0])

    for i in range(1, len(l)-1):
        temp = abs(l[i+1] - l[i])

        # Non-increasing difference, return
        if temp < dif:
            return False
        else:
            dif = temp

    # All differences are increasing
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is your friend:

```py
import numpy as np

x=np.array([1,3,7,2,-3])
(np.diff(abs(x[1:] - x[:-1])) > 0).all()  # returns False
```

If you're fancy a function, I would do like this:

```py
def expanding(l):
    # convert list to  np.array if a list was passed
    if isinstance(l, list):
        l = np.array(l)

    return (np.diff(abs(l[1:] - l[:-1])) > 0).all()
```

Comment: I don't think this does what OP is looking for. The question is to find whether the absolute difference between adjacent elements is strictly increasing, but this just finds whether the absolute values of the list elements are strictly increasing. It fails on `x=np.array([1,3,7,2,-4])`. Absolute differences are `[2, 4, 5, 6]`, but your implementation evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution using iterators:

```py
from itertools import tee, islice, starmap
from operator import lt, sub

def pairwise(x):
    a, b = tee(x, 2)
    return zip(a, islice(b, 1, None))

a = [1,3,7,2,-3]

pairs = pairwise(a) # this will be (a[0], a[1]), (a[1], a[2]), ...

# The next will produce the result abs(a[1]-a[0]), abs(a[2]-a[1]), ...
differences = map(abs, starmap(sub, pairs))

# This will be abs(a[2]-a[1])>abs(a[1]-a[0]), abs(a[3]-a[2])>abs(a[2]-a[1]), ...
cmp = starmap(lt, pairwise(differences))

# Differences strictly increases if all items in cmp are evaluated to True...
result = all(cmp)
print(result)
```

The output for such input is `False`

Comment: I think this answer would benefit from some code comments. Readers might not be familiar with the `itertools` and `operator` functions that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing the condition in an iterator that you then pass to [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#any) so to make sure that on the first occurrence of a non-expanding difference the iteration stops and `False` is returned.

Here is how this would look:

```py
def expanding(l):
    return not any((abs(l[i-1]-l[i])>=abs(l[i]-l[i+1]) for i in range(1,len(l)-1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def expanding(L):
    
    x=list()
    for i in range(len(L)-2):
        if abs(L[i+1]-L[i+2]) > abs(L[i]-L[i+1]):
            x.append(True)
        else:
            x.append(False)
    return all(x)
print(expanding([1,3,7,2,9]))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Explanation:
when we calculate difference list for the given list -> [2,4,5,7]
The difference list is strictly increasing.

```
Print(expanding([1,3,7,2,-3]))
```

Output:

```
False
```

Explanation:
when we calculate difference list for the given list -> [2,4,5,5]
The difference list is not increasing (i.e., 5>5 is False)

Answer (score -1):

Your logic is a little bit wrong. Once you know that one item is out of order you should answer False for the whole list.

```py
def expanding(l):
 for i in range(0,len(l)-3):
  if (abs(l[i+2]-l[i+1])<=abs(l[i+1]-l[i])):
   return False 
 return True
```

Answer (score -1):

## Code Written By Debkanta Mondal

## Python3

```
def expanding(l):
dif=[]
for x,y in zip(l,l[1:]):
    diff=abs(y-x)
    dif.append(diff)
return all(i<j for i,j in zip(dif,dif[1:]))
```

print(expanding([1,3,7,2,-3]) )